# How to test for an uninitialized mutable array

Tags: arrays, objective-c, initialization, nsmutablearray

I have corrupted a single object in a file.  When I load in the file, one of my mutable arrays (1) contains another mutable array (2) (loaded from the same file) which is uninitialized.  When I try to examine the array (2) with a for-in loop, I get:
-[NSMutableArray count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable array object"

I can get away with deleting array (2), but how do I test for it?

Comment: How do you load the file?

Comment: Using NSDocument.readFromData and NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData,  I retrieve an object (of type A) with a  property of type NSMutableArray. That array contains a nested chain of objects of type A  The problem object is a child of a child in that array.  I think the problem object was damaged before I archived the data.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this:

```
NSString* name = [item.children className];
if ([name isEqualToString:   @"__NSPlaceholderArray" ])
{
    item.children = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
else...
```